# Accessing a specific html tag via css

Tags: html, css

My html code is as below..

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="sub1">
<p><a href="http://uselesslink1"></a></p>
<p><a href="http://uselesslink2"></a></p>
</div>
<div class="sub2">
</div>
<p><a href="http://usefullink1"></a>
<a href="http://usefullink2"></a>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to access the useful links http://usefullink1 and http://usefullink2 using css selectors and use

> .main p a

But doing this I'm able to access both useful links and also the useless links which are inside the div sub1 inside div main.

With the above html structure is it possible to access only the usefull links and not the useless ones using css.

All help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you can use the attribute selector sth. like:

```
a[href="http://usefullink1"] {}
```

you could also use:

```
a[href~="usefullink"] {}
```

to match all containing the word "usefullink" in href

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Comment: Thanks for the answer but usefulllink is just a word I used to explain what I need, its going to keep changing in different pages with different urls. I will check to see if there is a common text amongst the useful links which does not exist in the useless links

Comment: looking at your code you could also try `.sub2 + p a` as all usefull links seem to be in the paragraph immediatly after the sub2

Comment: Or `.main>p a` since the paragraph with the wanted links is a direct descendant of the `.main` container as opposed to the paragraphs with the unwanted links.

Comment: @retterBadach really good one, actually better than your provided answer. Though I used attribute selector with a not clause as I got it early.

Comment: @Arnab. You must have found some common text which is at least helpful in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:nth-child` pseudoclass.

Like so : `.main p:nth-child(3) a`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 0):

I used attribute selector with a not clause.

```
.main p a:not([href*="text_in_all_useless_links_but_not_in_usefull_ones"])
```